# Jenkinsfile in a node with hostname

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to execute my job in a remote node passing the domain name as node arg.

Someone knows how to build this jenkinsfile?

I can't execute on the below way

```groovy
node('jenkins.mydomain.com') {
    build 'remote_exec'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two major issues within your two lines of code :-)

> ```
> node('jenkins.mydomain.com') {
> ```

This will build on a build agent with the **label** `jenkins.mydomain.com`. If you have only one build agent with this label given, this should work. But it's not the hostname! (Note: I'm not entirely sure if dots are allowed, but you could call it also `whateverserver`).

So this would allocate an executor slot (to run the code within the closure) on a build agent matching the given label...

> ```
> build 'remote_exec'
> ```

and then trigger yet **another** build for the job called `remote_exec`. This job (assuming it exists and you don't have this as a third issue^^) will then be built on an agent matching **its own** labels, ignoring the one given in the `node(label)` step.

If you want that the `remote_exec` job runs on a specific build agent only, then add the `node` step there!

Comment: Note that Jenkins will implicitly create a label for each Jenkins slave node, with the node declared name (the name you give to the node, or computer, object in the Jenkins config)